# Find common element in two from three arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I need to find elements of array which are hold in two of three given arrays.
It seems easy, but it's quite dificult and i have been strugling with this for few days.
I hope you can help me..

> For input:

> 1 2 3  5

> 1 2 4 6 7

> 1 3 4 8 9 10

> Output should be 3 (because 3,4,2 are common for two arrays)

> for input

> 1 2 3 4

> 2 3 4

> 3 4 1

> Output should be: 2  (because 1 is common for two arrays)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int duzina_prvog_niza = 0, duzina_drugog_niza = 0, duzina_treceg_niza = 0; //deklaracija duzina nizova
    printf("Unesite broj clanova prvog niza:\n");                              // unosimo duzine nizova i elemente nizova
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &duzina_prvog_niza);
    } while (0 > duzina_prvog_niza || duzina_prvog_niza > 50); // mozda ne bi trebalo stavljati gornju granicu za duzinu niza
    int niz1[duzina_prvog_niza];                               //zavisi kako vam sistem provjere radi, mislim da nece praviti problem
    // alociramo niz odgovarajuce duzine, iterativno popunimo niz uz odgovarajucu provjeru
    for (int i = 0; duzina_prvog_niza > i; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &niz1[i]);
        } while (0 > niz1[i] || niz1[i] > 10); // citaj elemente sve dok ne ucitas cifre iz odgovarajuceg opsega
    }
    for (int i = 0; duzina_prvog_niza > i; i++)
        printf(" %d  ", niz1[i]);
    printf("\n");
    // ** drugi niz **       -- bilo bi zgodno ovo sve strpati u jednu fju, meni je ovako bilo lakse..  c/p
    printf("Unesite broj clanova drugog niza:\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &duzina_drugog_niza);
    } while (0 > duzina_drugog_niza || duzina_drugog_niza > 50);
    int niz2[duzina_drugog_niza];
    // alociramo niz odgovarajuce duzine, iterativno popunimo niz uz odgovarajucu provjeru
    for (int i = 0; duzina_drugog_niza > i; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &niz2[i]);
        } while (0 > niz2[i] || niz2[i] > 10); // citaj elemente sve dok ne ucitas cifre iz odgovarajuceg opsega
    }
    for (int i = 0; duzina_drugog_niza > i; i++)
        printf(" %d  ", niz2[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // ** treci niz **
    printf("Unesite broj clanova treceg niza:\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &duzina_treceg_niza);
    } while (0 > duzina_treceg_niza || duzina_treceg_niza > 50);
    int niz3[duzina_treceg_niza];
    // alociramo niz odgovarajuce duzine, iterativno popunimo niz uz odgovarajucu provjeru
    for (int i = 0; duzina_treceg_niza > i; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &niz3[i]);
        } while (0 > niz3[i] || niz3[i] > 10); // citaj elemente sve dok ne ucitas cifre iz odgovarajuceg opsega
    }
    for (int i = 0; duzina_treceg_niza > i; i++)
        printf(" %d ", niz3[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //pocetna vrijednost brojaca mora biti nula!
    int brojac = 0;
    int pomocni_brojac = 0;
    // (S_1 intersect S_2) union (S_2 intersect S_3) union (S_3 intersect S_1)  -- matematicko rjesenje problema

    int x;
    int pomocni_niz[duzina_prvog_niza + duzina_drugog_niza + duzina_treceg_niza];
    for (int i = 0; duzina_prvog_niza + duzina_drugog_niza + duzina_treceg_niza > i; i++)
        pomocni_niz[i] = 0;

    int max;
    if(duzina_prvog_niza>=duzina_drugog_niza && duzina_prvog_niza>=duzina_treceg_niza) max=duzina_prvog_niza; 
    if(duzina_drugog_niza>=duzina_prvog_niza && duzina_drugog_niza>=duzina_treceg_niza) max=duzina_drugog_niza; 
    if(duzina_treceg_niza>=duzina_drugog_niza && duzina_treceg_niza>=duzina_prvog_niza) max=duzina_treceg_niza; 

    //prolazimo kroz sve elemente u sva tri niza i poredimo sve elemente sa svim elementima
    for (int i = 0; duzina_prvog_niza > i; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; duzina_drugog_niza > j; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; duzina_treceg_niza > k; k++)
            { // ako je element iz prvog niza jednak elementu iz drugog niza, ili je element
                if (((niz1[i] == niz2[j]) && (niz2[j] == niz3[k]) && (niz1[i] == niz3[k])))
                    1;
                else if ((niz1[i] != niz2[j]) && (niz2[j] == niz3[k]) && (niz1[i] != niz3[k]))
                    pomocni_niz[pomocni_brojac++] = niz2[j];
                else if ((niz1[i] == niz2[j]) && (niz2[j] != niz3[k]) && (niz1[i] != niz3[k]))
                    pomocni_niz[pomocni_brojac++] = niz1[i];
                else if ((niz1[i] != niz2[j]) && (niz2[j] != niz3[k]) && (niz1[i] == niz3[k]))
                    pomocni_niz[pomocni_brojac++] = niz2[j];
            }
        }
    }

int y = 0;
    for (int g = 0; pomocni_brojac > g; g++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; pomocni_brojac > l; l++)
        {
            if (pomocni_niz[g] == pomocni_niz[l])
                y++;
        }
        if (y == 0)
            brojac++;
        y = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; brojac > i; i++)
        printf("%d ", pomocni_niz[i]);
    printf("U dva od tri niza se nalazi %d clanova.", brojac);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid using two code tags, if not necessary.

Comment: In your second example shouldn't the output be 2 because 1 and 2 are common to 2 arrays? Assuming each array has unique items, I think the easiest solution I can think of would be to combine the arrays into a single array, then count the entries that exist exactly twice. That should be fairly easy with LINQ.

Comment: @techno Why is not 1 a common elements in the first example?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#? That doesn't look like C# code.

Comment: @techno Also it is unclear whether the arrays must be already sorted.

Comment: The main problem with your approach is that when you test multiple time the same values. nz1[i] and nz2[j] will be tested duzina_treceg_niza times. In your tests, if you have one equality and one difference the third test is always difference, so not useful. As if you have 2 equality, the third test will be equality.

Comment: *Please mention the constraints of the problem*. What is the possible array size? What is the possible size of array elements?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Numbers hold in all three arrays should not be counted.

Comment: @Slugsie Because im beginner and i wanted attention..

Comment: @AKSingh Array sizes are left to programmer, it's not specified. Size of each element is in range from 0 to 99.

Comment: @techno Can any value repeat in a single array? For example: `1 2 2 3` Is this a valid array?

Comment: Yes it is, and thats part of my headache

Comment: How should i modify @VladfromMoscow's code to work with repeated values? Whats your opinion?

Comment: @PtitXav Yeah, you are right. After hours of working on it I just typed all kinds of stuff that wont work.. Sorry for messy code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Program is really good I understand what you have done, but im now strugling with repeated values in array..

Comment: @techno *The output of your second example is wrong*. It should be `2` and ***not 1***.

Comment: @AKSingh Thank you, i wrote in hurry. I will edit it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a pretty fast solution to your problem. You will need three more arrays each having a size of 100. *Each array will record the frequency of any particular input array.* *The size of each frequency array is 100 since any input array will only consist of numbers in the range 0-99*.

For example:

```
Input arrays:

A: 1 2 3 5
B: 1 2 4 6 7
C: 1 3 4 8 9 10

Frequency arrays:

   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

A: 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
B: 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
C: 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

In the frequency arrays section:

*The top row denotes number which may be present in any input array* and *the rows below contains their frequency in each input array.*.

---

### Algorithm

```
1 : let frequencyA[100]
2 : let frequencyB[100]
3 : let frequencyC[100]
4 :
5 : for i = 0 to A.length-1
6 :     if (frequencyA[A[i]] == 0) frequencyA[A[i]]++
7 : for i = 0 to B.length-1
8 :     if (frequencyB[B[i]] == 0) frequencyB[B[i]]++
9 : for i = 0 to C.length-1
10:     if (frequencyC[C[i]] == 0) frequencyC[C[i]]++
11:
12: for i = 0 to 99
13:     if (frequencyA[i]+frequencyB[i]+frequencyC[i] == 2) Print i
```

The algorithm is pretty straight forward. The only that lines that deserve some explanation are mentioned below.

*Line 5-10:*

*For each input array, we loop though each of its element and record their frequency*. We record the frequency of any particular element only once, that is, ***if any element repeats** in a single array, we will record its frequency **only once***. This is made sure by the if condition which checks if we have recorded the frequency of any element before or not.

*Line 12-13:*

*We start a loop from 0 to 99 since they are the possible values of the array*. In the loop, we check *if sum of the frequency in the all the three frequency arrays of any element is 2 or not*. If its 2, then that element is present in present exactly twice else not.

---

### Time Complexity

The algorithm has a time complexity of `O(A.length + B.length + C.length)`. *It is a linear time complexity* which is quite fast.

---

I can not provide you with any code as I do not code in C a lot. I hope I have helped you. *If you face any trouble in understanding my answer, please do comment. I will be happy to update my answer*.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was also trying to do something similar. I was using fourth array, and adding numbers to it if i have match (for example if number is present in all three arrays i will add 10, but if it's present only in two i will add one).. But didn't succeded.

Comment: I did fail once when I was using only a single array to store frequency. Later I used this logic which worked. You are welcome.

Comment: I supose this will work fine if i have multiple repetitions in one array. Like 1 1 2 or 2 2 3. This method will work fine! I will try to code it right now

Comment: It will ouput `2` in this case. If the input array are `1 1 2` and `1 1 3`, then the algorithm will output `1`. It will not output `1 1`. If you need that, the algorithm will need some minor changes.

Comment: Yes, thats what i need. It needs to take just one value from one array.  For example:   2 2 2 2 2 2    | 3 3 3 3 2 | 1 3 4  Will give two as result.

Comment: In this case, it will output `2 3` since these two elements are found in only two arrays. Is this what you need? I got a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, it will look at the first array like it has just only one element 2, and the second array will have only two elements, 2 and 3. Which is what I need! Your solution is briliant!

Comment: I am glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters always use English words for identifiers. In this case your code will be readable for a larger auditorium. Otherwise it is difficult to read it.

This statement in your program

```
if (((niz1[i] == niz2[j]) && (niz2[j] == niz3[k]) && (niz1[i] == niz3[k])))
                    1;
```

does not make a sense.

If you need to output common elements that are present exactly in two of three arrays then there is no great sense to create a forth array with the size equal to the sum of sizes of the three arrays.

If the arrays can be unsorted and you may not sort the arrays then a straightforward approach can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const int a1[], size_t n1, const int a2[], size_t n2, const int a3[], size_t n3 )
{
    size_t total = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i1 = 0; i1 < n1; i1++ )
    {
        size_t count = 1;
        
        size_t i2 = 0;
        while ( i2 < n2 && a2[i2] != a1[i1] ) i2++;
        
        count += i2 != n2;
        
        size_t i3 = 0;
        while ( i3 < n3 && a3[i3] != a1[i1] ) i3++;
        
        count += i3 != n3; 
        
        if ( count == 2 )
        {
            ++total;
            printf( "%d ", a1[i1] );
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i2 = 0; i2 < n2; i2++ )
    {
        size_t i1 = 0;
        while ( i1 < n1 && a1[i1] != a2[i2] ) i1++;
        
        if ( i1 == n1 )
        {
            size_t i3 = 0;
            while ( i3 < n3 && a3[i3] != a2[i2] ) i3++;
        
            if ( i3 != n3 )
            {
                ++total;
                printf( "%d ", a2[i2] );
            }               
        }
    }
    
    if ( total != 0 ) putchar( '\n' );
    
    printf( "%zu\n", total );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
    int b[] = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 7 };
    int c[] = { 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10 };
    size_t n1 = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    size_t n2 = sizeof( b ) / sizeof( *b );
    size_t n3 = sizeof( c ) / sizeof( *c );

    f( a, n1, b, n2, c, n3 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 3 4 
3
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah i figured out I dont need fourth array. I will try your code right now. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Im thinking now how should i modify it to work with repeated values. What do you think? Im really sorry i didn't wrote that on my post immediatly.